# Problema com Procedure dinâmica de exclusão no mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

Andei realizando algumas pesquisas na internet mas não obtive muito sucesso. Estou montando uma procedure para excluir valores dinamicamente em relação as dependências de uma determinada tabela mas consigo passar apenas uma quantidade fixa de valores. Exemplo: Se eu preciso excluir 10 registros, tenho que inserir 10 variáveis no cabeçalho da minha procedure. Gostaria de encontrar uma forma dinâmica de resolver o problema. Segue a procedure base criada

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE EXCLUIR_USUARIO (IN PARAMETRO INT)
BEGIN

delete from socio_pessoa_juridica where emp_codigo in (PARAMETRO);
delete from empresa where emp_codigo in PARAMETRO;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Eu gostaria de encontrar um forma onde eu pudesse passar na call a quantidade que eu quisesse de chaves para exclusão sem ter que criar muitas variáveis.

Answer (score 0):

Não conheço uma forma nativa de fazer isso, algo semelhante ao [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) do javascript, normalmente nesse tipo de situação, é criado um parâmetro do tipo `varchar` que vai receber todos os dados já separados por vírgula:

```
delimiter //

create procedure excluir_usuario (in codigo_empresas varchar(255))
begin

  set @sql = concat('delete from socio_pessoa_juridica where emp_codigo in (', codigo_empresas, ')');
  prepare statement from @sql;
  execute statement;
  deallocate prepare statement;

  set @sql = concat('delete from empresa where emp_codigo in (', codigo_empresas, ')');
  prepare statement from @sql;
  execute statement;
  deallocate prepare statement;

end
//

delimiter ;
```

Com isso, podemos passar diferentes quantidades de parâmetros para o `in` no `where`, tornando um pouco mais dinâmica, porém ainda limitado:

```
set @codigo_das_empresas = '1,2,3,4,5' ;

call excluir_usuario(@codigo_das_empresas) ;
```

> Veja online: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cpmMCYjwNYeaTDgQ3pRE6g/2

---

Uma outra forma, que acredito ser mais voltada a receber diversos parâmetros distintos, é receber um json como parâmetro:

```
delimiter //

create procedure excluir_usuario (in params json)
begin

  set @empresas = json_unquote(json_extract(params, '$.empresas'));

  set @sql = concat('delete from socio_pessoa_juridica where emp_codigo in (', @empresas, ')');
  prepare statement from @sql;
  execute statement;
  deallocate prepare statement;

  set @sql = concat('delete from empresa where emp_codigo in (', @empresas, ')');
  prepare statement from @sql;
  execute statement;
  deallocate prepare statement;

end
//

delimiter ;
```

Aqui eu poderia receber diferentes parâmetros, de diferentes formas, acredito que o exemplo de varchar já lhe atende, mas fica aí o exemplo, talvez lhe dê outras ideias:

```
set @codigo_das_empresas = json_object( 'empresas', '1,2,3,4,5' );

call excluir_usuario(@codigo_das_empresas) ;
```

> Veja online: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9gqgYjvMSbSDpTymp4vF48/0